# Visual Studio Designer for Javascript App

Tags: javascript, c#, uml, visual-studio-designer

I'm writing an application and after some Proof-of-concept work I'm starting to design the app in UML. It will be an HTML5/Javascript app with a simple ASP.NET backend serving data over SignalR and AJAX to the front.

I want to design the C# classes and the JS "classes" in UML and I'm testing out the Visual Studio designer (2013) to see if it'll work. My problem is that the designer always create C# classes for every UML class, but some of these will be JS classes. Is there any way to turn off the code generation?

Comments on other/better tools are welcome.

Comment: I don't think you can turn off code generation... what about using a separate tool for JS "classes", such as [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net) - would that work in your case?

Comment: @CoolBots - I started diagramming it in Lucidchart in case I wanna fiddle with it on my Chromebook later. Last time I used Lucidchart I ran into some deal-breakers when doing sequence design; we'll see how it does this time.